# User Auth/Identity Service that takes care of social logins?

Tags: authentication, oauth, single-sign-on, openid, social-authentication

I am looking for a service similar to: Amazon Cognito, Okta, Auth0, OneLogin, Google Identity Platform, but with one requirement that the above mentioned services do not fulfil: the "social"/3rd party logins, like Facebook, Google, Twitter, Apple - to be handled not by the client, but by the platform *completely*.

If I understand correctly the docs and the descriptions of all mentioned services, if I want to add ability for users to auth via Facebook, I need to first go create an account on Facebook, create an app, get the keys, set it up at the service, repeat for google, repeat for Twitter, repeat for Apple... Is there a service like the ones I've mentioned, that take care of that for you? So I just tick a checkbox "I want my users to be able to auth via:

- [x] Facebook
- [x] Google
- [x] Twitter
- [x] Apple
- [  ] Whatnot"

And that's it.

I would like to pay a bit extra but I don't want to care about all those things myself *(especially with Facebook and it's constant updates and nudges)*.

Can someone recommend a services like that?

Comment: [Auth0](https://auth0.com/learn/social-login/) is the closest to what you're after, the others less so. There are two parts to to this: the setup of the "connection" and "using" it in your app to e.g. auth users.  Automating the identity provider (FB, Goog,...) portion of the setup is not implemented in commercial (or OSS) products for a number of reasons. The rest of your ask is already available.

Comment: I don't think that possible, each service like Apple or Google requires you to do those things, services like Auth0 just unify all of these different providers into one api but you still need to individually set up the keys for each provider